# Enviar resultado de procedimiento almacenado del controlador a la vista

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

Necesito enviar del controlador a la vista el resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado.

Esto es en mi controlador :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=DESKTOP-99IPRRD;initial catalog=RecursosHumanos;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot"))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DeduccionesNombre", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter paraminicio = new SqlParameter();
    paraminicio.ParameterName = "@inicio";
    paraminicio.Value = FechaDesde;

    SqlParameter paramfinal = new SqlParameter();
    paramfinal.ParameterName = "@final";
    paramfinal.Value = FechaHasta;

    SqlParameter paramareID = new SqlParameter();
    paramareID.ParameterName = "@areID";
    paramareID.Value = Area.AreId;

    SqlParameter paramarageID = new SqlParameter();
    paramarageID.ParameterName = "@ageID";
    paramarageID.Value = Agencia.AgeId;


    cmd.Parameters.Add(paraminicio);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramfinal);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramareID);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramarageID);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Éste es mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
drop procedure sp_DeduccionesNombre
go

create procedure sp_DeduccionesNombre @inicio datetime, @final datetime, @areID int, @ageID int
as

    select distinct d.DedId, d.DedDescripcion
     from Tbl_HistorialLaboral hl
     inner join Tbl_Empleado e on e.empid = hl.EmpId
     inner join Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado de on de.EmpId = e.EmpId
     inner join Tbl_Deducciones d on d.DedId = de.DedId
     where hl.areID = @areID and hl.AgeId = @ageID
     and (de.DetDedEmpFecha between @inicio and @final)
```

Éste es el resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado que trato de mostrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que estás utilizando el método ExecuteNonQuery. Este método se utiliza cuando no requieres revisar los resultados de una sentencia SQL.
Si requieres revisar el resultado, entonces debes utilizar el método ExecuteReader, que te devuelve un DataReader.
Ese DataReader te permitirá navegar por los registros / campos y regresarlos a tu vista a través de un model.

Supongamos que definiste una clase Deduccion

```
public class Deduccion
{
     public int DedId {get; set;}
     public string DedDescription {get; set; }
}
```

Entonces puedes utilizar el siguiente código...

```
List<Deduccion> deducciones=new List<Deduccion>(); 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=DESKTOP-99IPRRD;initial catalog=RecursosHumanos;integrated 

security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot"))


       {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DeduccionesNombre", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter paraminicio = new SqlParameter();
            paraminicio.ParameterName = "@inicio";
            paraminicio.Value = FechaDesde;

            SqlParameter paramfinal = new SqlParameter();
            paramfinal.ParameterName = "@final";
            paramfinal.Value = FechaDesde;

            SqlParameter paramareID = new SqlParameter();
            paramareID.ParameterName = "@areID";
            paramareID.Value = Area.AreId;

            SqlParameter paramarageID = new SqlParameter();
            paramarageID.ParameterName = "@ageID";
            paramarageID.Value = Agencia.AgeId;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(paraminicio);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramfinal);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramareID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramarageID);    

            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.read()) //Hay datos, entonces armamos el modelo para regresarlo a la vista
            {
                  deducciones.Add( 
                     new Deduccion { 
                           DedId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("DedId")),                 
                           DedDescripcion = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DedDescripcion"))
                     });
            }
            con.Close();

        }
   return View(deducciones); //Regresamos el modelo a la vista.
```

Comment: Buenas @Javier Reséndiz el Reader no me muestra los resultados y tambien necesito enviar eso a la vista ,  no a la consola

Comment: El código era a modo de ejemplo de recuperación de datos; sin embargo, ya actualicé la respuesta con un código más completo.